# Python with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list, imagedata

please, help me.

I have a list with path files as below:

```
[PosixPath('/home/angelo/Documentos/IA/Fast.ai-v3/nbs/dl1/papagaio/Papagaio_verdadeiro.jpg'),
 PosixPath('/home/angelo/Documentos/IA/Fast.ai-v3/nbs/dl1/papagaio/papagaio_amarelo.jpg'),
 PosixPath('/home/angelo/Documentos/IA/Fast.ai-v3/nbs/dl1/papagaio/zoom_RACAO_ALIMENTO_NUTROPICA_PAPAGAIO_AVES_PASSAROS1.jpg'),
 PosixPath('/home/angelo/Documentos/IA/Fast.ai-v3/nbs/dl1/papagaio/papagaio_ok.jpg'),
 PosixPath('/home/angelo/Documentos/IA/Fast.ai-v3/nbs/dl1/papagaio/alx_papagaio_20070327_01_original.jpeg')]
```

This list was created using get_image_files.

This is a list of images of parrots. Here in Brazil papagaio = parrot.

In order to use the filename for classification in machine learning, I tried to use the following regex:

```
pat = r'.[^\/.]+.jpg$'
```

However, after using it in an ImageDataBunch...

```
data_papagaio = ImageDataBunch.from_name_re(papagaio_path, papagaio_files, pat, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224, bs=bs
                                  ).normalize(imagenet_stats)
```

I received the following error message in return:

> IndexError: no such group

And I do not know how to solve it. Can someone help me?

Just for clarification, I'm trying to reproduce lesson 1 from the fast.ai course using some files on my hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metod is looking for a capturing group value, you need to set a pair of unescaped parentheses around the file name pattern.

Also, it seems you have both `jpg` and `jpeg`, so you need `jpe?g`, not just `jpg`.

Use

```
pat = r'([^/.]+)\.jpe?g$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6Fuqw/1)

Comment: @Angelo Glad it worked for you. Also, please consider upvoting if you found it helpful.